# rvest: select paragraphs (<p>) that do not contain links (<a>)

Tags: html, css, r, css-selectors, rvest

I am new to web scraping.
I am using the rvest package in R to scrape web content and I want to select paragraphs (

) that do not contain links ().

So far, I have not been very successful with this approach:

```
html <- read_html("https://www.news4teachers.de/2023/08/schaemt-euch-deutschland-steht-vor-den-vereinten-nationen-am-pranger-weil-es-die-inklusion-an-schulen-verweigert/")

html |>
  html_elements("article") |>
  html_elements("p") |>
  html_elements(":not(a)")
```

Comment: All answers are very helpful, and I highly appreciate your support. @Till 's answer is the best for me (noop), as it does not require any XPath knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the pseudo-class `:has()` is not supported by
`selectr`/`cssselect` which are used by `rvest` for parsing css selectors.
Otherwise something like this would work:

```r
# html |>
#  html_elements("article") |>
#  html_elements("p:not(:has(a))")
```

We can work around this by converting the `xml_nodelist` to `character` and
`stringr::str_detect()` which `<p>` elements have an `<a>` in them. Then we
subset the `xml_nodelist` to only include those that don’t have link/`<a>` in
them.

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

html <-
  read_html(
    "https://www.news4teachers.de/2023/08/schaemt-euch-deutschland-steht-vor-den-vereinten-nationen-am-pranger-weil-es-die-inklusion-an-schulen-verweigert/"
  )

all_p <-
  html |>
  html_elements("article") |>
  html_elements("p")

has_link <- all_p |> as.character() |> str_detect("</a>")

all_p[!has_link]
#> {xml_nodeset (13)}
#>  [1] <p>GENF. <strong>„Schämt Euch!“ – so heißt es auf einem Transparent, das ...
#>  [2] <p><script charset="utf-8" async consent-original-src-_="https://platfor ...
#>  [3] <p>Es ist fast schon dreist, wie Deutschland auf die offizielle Staatenp ...
#>  [4] <p>Auch in einer gemeinsamen Stellungnahme von einem Bündnis deutscher N ...
#>  [5] <p>„In keinem Bildungsbereich – von der Kita über Schule, Ausbildung und ...
#>  [6] <p>Die Ausführungen der Bundesregierung im Staatenbericht, so heißt es w ...
#>  [7] <p>Sonderpädagoginnen und -pädagogen würden immer noch weitestgehend für ...
#>  [8] <p>Die Einführung inklusiver Bildung in Regelschulen sei von erheblichem ...
#>  [9] <p><script charset="utf-8" async consent-original-src-_="https://platfor ...
#> [10] <p><script charset="utf-8" async consent-original-src-_="https://platfor ...
#> [11] <p>Der Rechtsanspruch auf inklusive Schulbildung sei in den meisten Bund ...
#> [12] <p><iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security= ...
#> [13] <p> </p>
```

Comment: All answers are very helpful, and I highly appreciate your support. @Till 's answer is the best for me (noop), as it does not require any XPath knowledge

Answer (score 3):

To get all the `<p>` tags which do not contain any `<a>` tags, you can use an xpath expression:

```r
html_elements(html, xpath = "//article/div/p[not(descendant::a)]") 
#> {xml_nodeset (13)}
#>  [1] <p>GENF. <strong>„Schämt Euch!“ – so heißt es auf einem Transparent, das ...
#>  [2] <p><script charset="utf-8" async consent-original-src-_="https://platfor ...
#>  [3] <p>Es ist fast schon dreist, wie Deutschland auf die offizielle Staatenp ...
#>  [4] <p>Auch in einer gemeinsamen Stellungnahme von einem Bündnis deutscher N ...
#>  [5] <p>„In keinem Bildungsbereich – von der Kita über Schule, Ausbildung und ...
#>  [6] <p>Die Ausführungen der Bundesregierung im Staatenbericht, so heißt es w ...
#>  [7] <p>Sonderpädagoginnen und -pädagogen würden immer noch weitestgehend für ...
#>  [8] <p>Die Einführung inklusiver Bildung in Regelschulen sei von erheblichem ...
#>  [9] <p><script charset="utf-8" async consent-original-src-_="https://platfor ...
#> [10] <p><script charset="utf-8" async consent-original-src-_="https://platfor ...
#> [11] <p>Der Rechtsanspruch auf inklusive Schulbildung sei in den meisten Bund ...
#> [12] <p><iframe class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security= ...
#> [13] <p> </p>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could select all the `<p>` tags and then filter them in R if they have any `<a>` tags. For example

```
html |>
  html_elements("article") |>
  html_elements("p") |>
  Filter(function(x) {
    length(html_element(x, "a"))<1
  }, x=_)
```